# KeyError: 1744843431 when loading a pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

so I was trying to load the pickled file like I used to do using

```
set_x = pickle.load(open('retaindata/h50_cl2_all.visits.train', 'rb'), encoding='bytes')
```

But somehow it gives me an error that I couldn't find a solution to on google:
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gpdy.png)

Can someone help and let me know what went wrong?

Comment: where did the pickle file come from?

Comment: Have you changed the code since saving that pickle? If so, can you run the last version of the code (you _are_ using git or svn or some other form of revision control, right?) and see if it still loads the same pickle?

Comment: It's previously processed for another model (retain, an RNN based model) and dumped so we don't need to process them again to use for other models. Yep, and I will try to see if last version of code gives some results. Thanks!